# Next Scripts Social Networks Auto Poster facebook

Tags: wordpress, facebook

I would like to install Next Scripts: Social Networks Auto Poster, using wordpress and facebook. I did everything as described here 
http://www.nextscripts.com/instructions/facebook-social-networks-auto-poster-setup-installation/

I am doing this for community in facebook. Everything was okey, but when I click  "Authorize Your Facebook Account <=== Авторизировать ваш аккаунт ===",
I get this error:

**Invalid Scopes: user_groups. This message is only shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions if present. Please read the documentation for valid permissions at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions**

I authorized by a single login everywhere in facebook. The above link  did not help me too.

Maybe somebody knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user_groups` got removed with v2.4 of the Graph API, you can´t use it in new Apps anymore. The replacement would be `user_managed_groups`. you may need to talk to the script creators about that, they have to change the permission.

Btw, "autoposting" scripts are usually not allowed, be careful with those and don´t spam.

Comment: Thank you) Developers of SNAP have fixed this error.

Comment: you´re welcome. please don´t forgot to select my answer as correct, let´s keep the answer rate on stackoverflow hight ;)